# Redirecting from directory to root [PHP]

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my website. I have a file /domain/includes/_dash-notifications.php and inside this file I have a function that should redirect me to index.php: header("Location: index.php"). This doesn't work because it tries to find index.php inside /includes directory. Tried different approaches none of which helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this: header("Location: /index.php")

By using / you specify an absolute url so it will load index.php in your web root folder.

Comment: Thanks, this  helped :)